# Find all the numbers in an array whoes difference less than or equal to K

Tags: python, arrays

I want to find two numbers `A[i]` and `A[j]` whose difference is less than or equal to `K`, I need to store index of such numbers in array L (Left) R (Right) and return L & R

```py
def fun(A, k): 
    n = len(A)
    l = 0
    r = n-1
    # traverse the array for the two elements 
    while l<r: 
        if (A[l] - A[r] <= n):
            return A[l],A[r]
        elif (A[l] - A[r] < n): 
            l += 1
        else: 
            r -= 1
    return 0

# Driver code to test above function 
A = [3.5,5,6,12,13] 
k = 1.7
print(fun(A, k))
```

**Expected output:**

```
L[0,0,1,3,3],R[1,2,2,4,4]
```

Comment: Why is `0, 2` in your output?  Isn't the difference there greater than 1.7?

Comment: On top of that, you seem to be looking for `A[l] - A[r] <= n` where `n` is the size of the `list`; you're comparing computed values from `A` with the length of `A`??? Did you perhaps mean to use `k` *somewhere* in this code?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh the example I'm solving is having same output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `itertools.combinations` to get all possible combinations, then test their differences and append if needed.

```
from itertools import combinations

def fun(A, k):
    l, r = [], []
    for (x_idx, x_val), (y_idx, y_val) in combinations(enumerate(A), 2):
        if abs(x_val - y_val) <= k:
            l.append(x_idx)
            r.append(y_idx)
    return l, r
```

Test:

```
A = [3.5,5,6,12,13] 
k = 1.7
print(fun(A, k))
# ([0, 1, 3], [1, 2, 4])
```

Though it's not your expected output, I feel like your expected output may have a few errors according to your logic.

Comment: cant we do this via while loop?

Comment: @June Why? When iterating a sequence, a `for` loop is essentially always better.

Comment: ohh got it, is this O(n)?

Comment: Had a similar idea (but avoiding manual `list` construction in favor of making it a generator and using `zip` to unpack the results). Not worth a separate answer, but [posted here for comparison](https://tio.run/##VY7BCsIwEETv@Yo5JhILbamC2EPvnryKSNUEl6ZJSdND/fmaiCjOadjZt7PDHB7Olov2rgcF5YNzZgT1g/MBN9dfybaBnB2Xu9LQk@WNRCd2DFHaeXBzIQkjJLhPzguQ/SO5slOvfBsUb@Ja8YGTSKO9jtxgnbh9je6XJc2kzB3vhnicsQY1TmVWyUpuZF7IvDyzLs7ybMsOEsdonzTw1fdPwQZPNvAUimV5AQ "Python 3 – Try It Online").

Comment: @June Because a call to `combinations` is required, which generates `nCr(length, 2)` sequences, it's `O(n * (n - 1) / 2)`, not `O(N)`. I do not believe further optimization is possible.

Comment: @Tomothy32: If the input is guaranteed ordered (the OP's is ordered, unclear if it's guaranteed), [a `O(n log n)` solution is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54702286/364696) (meaningfully cheaper than the approximately `O(n ** 2)` solution here). It's still possible if it *isn't* ordered, but it's probably not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

An `O(n log n)` solution that exploits the ordering in your example `A` (if it's not ordered, you can always pay `O(n log n)` a second time to sort it, though preserving the original indices would likely make it not worth the complexity):

```
from bisect import bisect

def fun(A, k):
    # Add A.sort() if A not guaranteed to be sorted
    for l, x in enumerate(A):
        for r in range(l+1, bisect(A, x+k, l+1)):
            yield l, r
```

This uses [the `bisect.bisect` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect) to find the end point for each start point in `O(log n)` time, making the overall cost `O(n log n)`. It doesn't even need to directly test most values against `k`, since `bisect` finds the end of the indices which meet the different criteria, and all values in between definitely meet it.

Rather than building the `list` manually, I've made this a generator function that can be converted to the `L` and `R` values with `zip` and unpacking:

```
>>> A = [3.5,5,6,12,13] 
>>> k = 1.7
>>> L, R = zip(*fun(A, k))
>>> print(L, R)
(0, 1, 3), (1, 2, 4)
```

You could do it with `list`s explicitly:

```
def fun(A, k):
    L, R = [], []
    for l, x in enumerate(A):
        newr = range(l+1, bisect(A, x+k, l+1))
        L += [l] * len(newr)
        R.extend(newr)
    return L, R
```

but I kind of like the generator->zip->unpack approach for letting Python do most of the work. Either way, the theoretical cost of `O(n log n)` is better than `O(n * (n - 1) / 2)` (roughly `O(n ** 2)`).